# Segmentation Fault in a multi-threaded server

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, network-programming, pthreads

I have been developing a multi-threaded server (using Pthreads) for a network for about 2 months now, under Linux (Ubuntu 11.04 64-bit kernel 2.6.38).

The code is about 7000 lines of `C` at the moment. I have been using it in the network where multiple clients connect to it and get served. It has been running quite smoothly.

Suddenly I am facing a bit of strange problem. Every now and then (about 1 out of 10 times) the server crashes due to segmentation fault. I have looked all over the code but can not seem to find the actual reason behind this. Can anyone guide me on this as to what may be going wrong here or what things I should try to find the actual bug?

Comment: Did you run the code through a debugger?

Comment: You may have a core dump that you can look with gdb. It may help you to find, at least which variable was accessed to cause this error.

Comment: I did use intel vtune to profile the code but couldn't find the problem. valgrind seems to be appropriate for this. Sorry dont have much experience with debuggers. Valgrind will be the most appropriate ?

Comment: I would look at the core dump first. Once you see what code is faulting, you can make a judgment was the most appropriate way to debug it is. Though I'd run `valgrind` no matter what, even if it's not the best way to catch this particular issue.

Comment: Thanks alot. Will do that. Much appreciated :)

Comment: This is the machine's way of telling you: whoa, you're developing too fast, slow down! Let me throw a bug in your way to help you do that.

Answer (score 3):

1. Enable core file generation. When the application crashes, load up the debugger
2. run your application using valgrind with memory check
3. write unit tests. Lots of them, and increase coverage to 100%.
4. stress test your application using [valgrind's hellgrind](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#helgrind) to test multithreaded applications

Comment: Aiming at 100% coverage is often less productive than it is worth, but in general unit tests are a great idea. See http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3159-testing-like-the-tsa

Comment: Unit tests are mostly insignificant in a multithreaded setup. How do you mock/fake threads? How do you ensure that you cover every possible thread synchronization combination? If you know the answer: please start writing and publishing papers on it, because the industry would love a new Dijkstra...

Comment: I think it is highly unlikely that a unit test could spontaneously discover the problem. Once the problem is identified, however, a unit-test may be able to reproduce it (and ensure it does not regress).

Comment: @JörgenSigvardsson Right. Different kind of tests are needed to test multi threaded applications. edited answer

Comment: @MarkR Unit tests are kind of a safety net to catch many bugs, and allow easier refactoring. They are not a silver bullet, and will certainly not catch all errors. Having unit tests in place, statistics are saying that 30% of bugs are caught. The OP didn't complain he has unit tests, so my point it valid.

Comment: Unit tests may provide a false sense of security, and in this case, it does. There is no real good way to perform unit tests on multithreaded setups, without either modifying what you are observing, or model a reality that does not reflect the actual site. Microsofts Chess project is probably the closest thing to a good approach I've seen, although it's unwieldy, because as soon as your code expands beyond trivial examples, it becomes too inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

100% coverage isn't realistic, but 85%-95% can reasonably happen with diligence.

About why weird errors happen:
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/checking-early.html

You said this started happening suddenly.  Hopefully you've been using a source code control system like Mercurial or Git or SVN.  If you have (or perhaps you have nightly backups?), you probably should look back at the changes made at about the time the problems started, trying to find the error, which is likely an undefined memory reference.